# Serve file with Flask's send_file then redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I want to download a file and at the same time redirect to a new page. The user is shown a page with a link for the download. When they click it, I want to start the download then redirect to another page so they can't keep clicking it. However, I can only seem to get one or the other to work.

```python
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, session, request, flash, send_file
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from pytube import YouTube
import os
import random, string
import re

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'
session_id = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=6))

class url_form(FlaskForm):
    link = StringField('Enter link of YouTube video you would like to convert...')
    audio = BooleanField('Audio Only')
    submit = SubmitField('Convert')

def download_video(link, just_audio):
    yt = YouTube(link)
    download_path = 'conversions/'
    #global myvar
    if just_audio == True:
        stream = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
        tag = 'video'
    else:
        stream = yt.streams.filter(adaptive=True).first()
        tag = 'audio only'

    download_video.name = yt.title
    download_video.cleanString = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', '', download_video.name)
    download_video.thumbnail = yt.thumbnail_url
    download_video.path = stream.download(filename = download_video.cleanString, output_path = download_path)
    return

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    result = False
    form = url_form()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['link'] = form.link.data

        if form.audio.data:
            just_audio = True
        else:
            just_audio = False

        session['just_audio'] = just_audio
        link = session.get('link')
        just_audio = session.get('just_audio')
        download_video(link, just_audio)
        #download_video(link, just_audio)
        #return send_file(download_video.path, attachment_filename=download_video.cleanString + '.mp4', as_attachment=True)
        return redirect(url_for('conversion_complete'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, result=result)


@app.route('/conversion_complete', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def conversion_complete():
    return render_template('conversion_complete.html')


@app.route('/download/', methods=['GET'])
def download():
    return send_file(download_video.path, attachment_filename=download_video.cleanString + '.mp4', as_attachment=True)
    return render_template('result.html')
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Conversion Complete</h1>
    <a href='download' target='blank' type='button'><button class='btn btn-default'>Download!</button></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot add two returns for download view. Try to use something AJAX for request and use javascript to redirect on success.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I'll do some research on this now and see if I can get somewhere. (Very little Ajax/is experience). On a sidenote, you're not Arun K Sekher are you? I knew a guy years ago with that name who knew his stuff!

Comment: any solution here?